# call viewDidDisappear in Tabbar based Application

Tags: iphone

I am using tab bar based iPhone application.I have set `NSTimer` in first two tabs.i want to invalidate this timer. so i am invalidating in `viewDidDisappear`. But when i am clicking on different tab, it will never call `viewDidDisappear`. I don't know how to call this method?please help me...thanking you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

are you put `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];` in `viewWillDisappear` some time it happaned becouse we forget to put this line in to `viewWillDisappear`

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

}
```

Comment: This should also be done in any subclasses of the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

set time invalid in `viewWillDisappear:` method , like bellow..

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
      [yourTimer invalidate];
       yourTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: you put this code in viewWillDisappear method instead of viewDidDisappear??

Comment: here is my code:timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:(self) selector:@selector(updateWeb) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; written into viewDidAppear.-(void)updateWeb{
    [webview reload];
    [app hideLoader];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (timer) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
    [webview stopLoading];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

Comment: i also add like this in my one project see my code.. timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0                                             target:self                                           selector:@selector(targetMethod:)                                           userInfo:nil                                            repeats:YES];-(void) targetMethod: (NSTimer *) theTimer 
{
    [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
}